# Using an uncountable noun and 'none'

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Today I came across the following sentence:

> We asked for help and were given none.

It feels and sounds right to me.  However, after decomposing *none* into *not one*, it becomes apparent that you can't have *one help* in this context.  So is *none* the right word to use originally?

If so, what does that say for the *none = not one* equivalence?  If not, then what is a better way to phrase it?

Comment: _Help_ is also used as plural noun, though.

Comment: People who insist that *none* is equivalent to "not one" also use it to claim that *none* must be used only with singular verb agreement, which also doesn't agree with the facts.  The domain of *none* overlaps with that of "not one", but *none* is still a separate entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *none* in the example sentence is correct.

When *none* is used with countable nouns, it means *not one*. However, *none* can also be used with uncountable nouns, in which case it means *not any*.

Comment: can you give an example sentence of "none" being used with uncountable nouns .

Comment: @Geek _How much sugar is there in Coke Zero? **None**._

Comment: @Flater Is the usage of 'none' in "None of the meat was fit to eat." correct?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Yes.

Answer (score 0):

"We asked for help and were given none."

This is correct.  We asked and we were given.  If "none" was the subject of "given," it would be written "We asked for help and none was given."  "None were given" would sound odd because in this case "none" is not plural (nor is "help").

Answer (score -1):

About using a plural or a singular verb with *none*, the NOAD reports:

> It is sometimes held that none can take only a singular verb, never a plural verb: *none of them is coming tonight*, rather than *none of them are coming tonight*. There is little justification, historical or grammatical, for this view.
>   None is descended from Old English *nān*, meaning *not one*, and has been used for around a thousand years with both a singular and a plural verb, depending on the context and the emphasis needed.

I would rather write the sentence you reported as

> We asked for help and none was given us.

As for the equivalence between *none* and *not one*, the meaning of *none* is *not any*, *no person*, or *no one* when used as pronoun, and *by no amount*, *not at all* when used as adverb and it is followed by the definite article.

> Don't use any more water, or there'll be none left for me.
>   None could match her looks.
>   It is made none the easier by the differences in approach.

Replace *none* with *not one* in the first sentence, and you get a sentence that is not correct.

> (*) Don't use any more water, or there'll be not one left for me.

Comment: But by decomposing your preferred sentence: "We asked for help and not one was given us", the same problem occurs: it's a report on "one help."  I don't think you answered the question.

Comment: See the last part of my answer where I explain that, although _none_ means also _not one_, you cannot simply replace _none_ with _not one_.